# Device token not generating iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am facing issue while generating the device token with the real device.
I am debugging device and device token is not generating.
Sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Please let me know what could be issue.
Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes not: On the same device? Various Devices ? Various iOS versions ? Is the error callback called?

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to ask same thing twice. In both of your questions, you didn't provide any details, code, iOS version, etc., you don't show any research effort. I strongly recommend you to remove one of your questions, and include as much details about the issue as you can in the question you keep. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Did you put below in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate.m`?

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    NSLog(@"ios8 app");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"lower ios8 app");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I, too, am having trouble getting device tokens.

My projects stopped generating device tokens when it was "erased" and "installed" around 10 hours ago.
Also in the Korean iOS Developers forum, some people have been reporting problems with APNS tokens not generating in the past 10 hours.

There may be something wrong with some of the sandbox APNS servers.

- Last checked time
  2016-04-27 22:43 PM +0900 GMT : No device token, Push Notification Not Arriving.

Comment: is this really happening @CheeseLemon?

Comment: Yes right now everybody is reporting now it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

@GopalDevra could you be more clear? Anyway, I have this code for Parse, maybe it's not your case, but you can get the idea.

You can use didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in AppDelegate.m like:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

**Edited**

Have you put this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

```
// - Push notifications
// -- Register for Push Notitications
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];

[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];

//-- Set Notification
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];        
}

//--- your custom code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
I have tried these lines of code.
But not working

Comment: @J.Lopes Are you able yourself to get a device token from sandbox APN today?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea The last device token I got today was at: 2016-04-27T03:57:06.942Z so I don't know if it stopped after that. I will check it out.

Comment: There are ongoing discussions in Apple Developer forums indicating that others are also failing to get device tokens at the moment, from sandbox APN.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method,

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) 
    {
      print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
```

You will get answer, why token is not generated.

Comment: Edit for objective c:-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    
}